# elasticsearch synonyms gives empty results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using `elasticsearch-7.0.0`.

I have created an index with following configuration:

```
{
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "analysis":{
            "analyzer":{
                "synonym":{
                    "tokenizer":"whitespace",
                    "filter":[
                        "synonym"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "synonym":{
                    "type":"synonym",
                    "synonyms_path":"synonyms.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Content of `synonyms.txt` :

```
ny, new york, big apple
ca, california, socal, norcal
```

I have a document as:

```
{
    "name":"Berry's Burritos",
    "description":"Best burritos in New York",
    "address": {
        "street":"230 W 4th St",
        "city":"New York",
        "state":"NY",
        "zip":"10014"
    },
    "location":[40.7543385,-73.976313],
    "tags":["mexican","tacos","burritos"],
    "rating":"4.3"
}
```

With this query, where the value is as in the doc. (not synonym), it gives the result.

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":{
                "range":{
                    "rating":{
                        "gte":4.0
                    }
                }
            },
            "must":{
                "match":{
                    "address.state":"ny"                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But replacing `address.state : "ny"` with `address.state : "new york"` yields no result.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Share the index mapping as well

Comment: I haven't added any mapping configuration. Is mapping necessary too?

Comment: Yes. You need to specify the analyzer for the field(s) while creating the mapping